# How can I recover XLM from a BlockEQ wallet?

Tags: xlm, keypair

I have a chunk of XLM sitting in a BlockEQ wallet on OS X. Every "send" operation seems to result in a "payment failed" error. Is there another way to extract the funds? BlockEQ is using a "24 words" private key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any stellar wallet that supports importing your "24 word" seed phrase (Keywords: BIP39, HD-Wallet, mnemonic) should work. Ledger hardware wallets should also work.

-- or --

Here is a tool to generate your private keys from your 24 words seed phrase:

https://iancoleman.io/bip39/

(you may also download and execute it on an offline computer for security reasons)

Enter your 24 word mnemonic phrase at "BIP39 Mnemonic" and select "Coin" = "XLM Stellar". Get the first private key from the list (starts with S...) and import it into any stellar wallet like [stellar account viewer](https://www.stellar.org/account-viewer/).

Comment: i repeatedly got "invalid mnemonic", until i finally doublechecked my 24 words again -- and sure as hell there was a typo! i successfully recovered my private key now, thanks a lot.